# Azure october 2012 sdk - how to delete a table entity without retrieving it first?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

In the previous version we could do this to delete an entity without knowing whether it exists.

```
svc = new TestContext();
item = new TestEntity("item2pk", "item2rk");
svc.AttachTo("TestTable", item, "*");
svc.DeleteObject(item);
svc.SaveChanges();
```

[(source)](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/deleting-entities-from-windows-azure-without-querying-first)

The new TableOperations doesn't have this syntax. Do I have to use this old method or is there a way? I'd like to be consistent because now all my code use the new classes for version 2.

edit: the title was misleading

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to use `TableOperation.Delete`:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
var table = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient()
                            .GetTableReference("tempTable");
table.CreateIfNotExists();

// Add item.
table.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(new TableEntity("MyItems", "123")));

// Load items.
var items = table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<TableEntity>());
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.PartitionKey + " - " + item.RowKey);
}

// Delete item (the ETAG is required here!).
table.Execute(TableOperation.Delete(new TableEntity("MyItems", "123") { ETag = "*" }));
```

The delete only works for entities that exist. Even though the old client had the `ContinueOnError` option, it was not compatible with the `Batch` operation ([as explained here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx)).

The only way to have a successful batch of Deletes if you don't know that the entity exists it to add them first (or replace them if they already exist):

```
var ensureItemsBatch = new TableBatchOperation();
ensureItemsBatch.InsertOrReplace(new MyEntity("MyItems", "123") { Active = false });
ensureItemsBatch.InsertOrReplace(new MyEntity("MyItems", "456") { Active = false });
ensureItemsBatch.InsertOrReplace(new MyEntity("MyItems", "789") { Active = false });
table.ExecuteBatch(ensureItemsBatch);

var deleteItemsBatch = new TableBatchOperation();
deleteItemsBatch.Delete(new MyEntity("MyItems", "123") { ETag = "*" });
deleteItemsBatch.Delete(new MyEntity("MyItems", "456") { ETag = "*" });
deleteItemsBatch.Delete(new MyEntity("MyItems", "789") { ETag = "*" });
table.ExecuteBatch(deleteItemsBatch);
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not work, even with the * ETag. I get StorageException: "The specified resource does not exist."

Comment: Clarification: Your code works, but in my case, the item does indeed not exist. How can I get it to ignore that?

Comment: Clarification 2: I can't just catch the exception, because this is actually done in a batch operation.

Comment: You can't delete an entity that does not exist. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 10):

I use my own method which catches the StorageException which occurs when the entity doesn´t exist. Additionally it returns whether the entity was deleted as bool.

```
public bool DeleteTableEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
{
    try
    {
        _table.Execute(TableOperation.Delete(new TableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey) { ETag = "*" }));
        return true;
    }
    catch (StorageException e)
    {
        if (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            return false;
        throw;
    }
}
```

The _table member variable is of type CloudTable (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable).
For this example I use the assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll, v2.1.0.3 installed with NuGet.